# how to apply validation if I using wicked gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use wicked gem for devide page in multistep.

But there is one model.
How can i fire validation on this two different page

Is there any solution please help me...

There is two controller first is book_controller from that it enter in multistep controller from this controller it update book params.

and there is one model book_model form where i write validation

but in first page it fire all validation.
actually i want to fire few validation on first page and remaining validation in steps from

Comment: This issue is resolved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374040/how-validation-is-done-using-wicked

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on server side.
So, the solution do it on the client side.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations