# how validation is done using wicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wicked-pdf

I have a users_controller and a user_steps_controller which has three steps :business, :payment and :login

In the user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :fname, :lname, :email, :mob, :country, :state, :suburb, :postal ,:add
end
```

while checking validation if i put some random values then also it is giving errors

```
Fname can't be blank
Lname can't be blank
Email can't be blank
Mob can't be blank
Country can't be blank
State can't be blank
Suburb can't be blank
Postal can't be blank
Add can't be blank
```

Please help me out

This is my users_controller

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:id])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id]= @user.id
      @user.update_attributes(user_params )
      redirect_to user_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit( :fname, :lname, :email, :mob, :gender_male, :gender_female, :country, :state, :suburb, :postal ,:add, :cmpyname, :abnacn, :cmpyadd, :cmpydet,:cash, :paypal,:bsb,:usrname,:password_hash, :password_salt, :selcat, :protit, :prodes)
  end
```

user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
validates :fname, :lname, :email, :mob, :country, :state, :suburb, :postal ,:add, :presence => true

attr_accessor :current_step

validates_presence_of :cmpyname, :abnacn, :cmpyadd, :cmpydet, if: -> { current_step?(:business) }
validates_presence_of :usrname,:password_hash, :password_salt, :selcat, :protit, :prodes, if: -> { current_step?(:login) }

def current_step?(step_key)
  current_step == step_key
end

end
```

user_steps_controller

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :business, :login, :payment

def show
  @user = current_user
  render_wizard
end

  def update

    @user = current_user
    params[:user][:current_step] = step
    @user.update_attributes(user_params )
    render_wizard @user

  end

 private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit( :cmpyname, :abnacn, :cmpyadd, :cmpydet,:cash, :paypal,:bsb,:usrname,:password_hash, :password_salt, :selcat, :protit, :prodes)
  end
end
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to post in some of your form code you are using to test out validation.

Comment: please post your controller code, that triggers User creation

Comment: I posted users_controller @Stanislav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem is here:

```
@user = User.new(params[:id])
```

I'm assuming `params[:id]` is `nil`, because otherwise that would fail. Basically, your instantiating a `User` with no data supplied and trying to save it. So clearly those validations you have supplied will fail. If you're actually submitting a form with user data you need to pass `user_params` you've already defined as follows:

@user = User.new(user_params)

If you need to have validations occur on your User model in different steps, you'll need to have the validations run conditionally dependent on the state of the form:

```
class User 
  attr_accessor :current_step
  validates_presence_of :business_related_attr, if: -> { current_step?(:business) }

  def current_step?(step_key)

    current_step.blank? || current_step == step_key
  end
end
```

Comment: but now next step validation errors are coming if i am on the first page without going to next steps...please help me out on this @faraz

Comment: I unfortunately need to go to sleep now. Post another question with the details, and hopefully someone else can help!

Answer (score 3):

user.rb

```
def current_step?(step_key)
  current_step == step_key
end
```

user_steps_controller.rb

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :personal, :social

  def show
    @user = current_user
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    params[:user][:current_step] = step
    @user.attributes = user_params
    render_wizard @user
  end

private

  def redirect_to_finish_wizard(options = nil)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up."
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :current_step, :date_of_birth, :bio, :twitter_username, :github_username, :website)
  end
end
```

This method will work for you.

Comment: now the first page works fine but it is not showing validation on other steps    @user123

Comment: added user.rb @user123

Comment: how are you setting current_step from user_steps_controller?

Comment: I have tried it and it's working. What error you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting validations on user_steps

Comment: Will you please update your user_steps_controller? so that I can help you.

Comment: Please add :current_step in def user_params of user_steps_controller. In your params current_step is not permitted and that is a problem.

Comment: oh yes that works i am upvoting your answer....please upvote my question too @user123